# How to Create a Contact with PhoneGap and Sencha Touch 2

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I'm building an example app using Sencha Touch 2 and PhoneGap.

Originally it was just a Sencha Touch 2 app that showed some static text, specifically contact information for any random person. Now, I've integrated PhoneGap into the project because I'd like to be able to add that contact information to the device (currently an android emulator). I've gone through the code here at:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contact

But I haven't been able to get it working.

Does anybody have an example of how to get this going.

**TL;DR** - How can I take static contact information from Sencha Touch 2 javascript view and add it to the contacts list on an Android emulator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of phonegap are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to come back to this...

I used this guide as an example on how to get started with both of these technologies, in Eclipse, for Android.

[Packaging a Sencha Touch 2 application with PhoneGap for Android](http://andidog.de/blog/2012/06/packaging-a-sencha-touch-2-application-with-phonegap-for-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Version are very important when you're reading a documentation.

So, as you're working with PhoneGap 1.8.1, I suggest you refer to the [documentation for Phonegap 1.8.1](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/index.html) and not for the version 1.0.0 (the link you pasted leads to the documentation for PhoneGap 1.0.0).

Come back if you still have any trouble making it work

Hope this helps

Comment: I was looking for something more like a coding sample, I mean can you put PhoneGap and Sencha code in the same page, etc. Or a sample of how to mix the two...

Comment: Sencha and PhoneGap are two different frameworks. The first one helps you build a web application that looks like a mobile native app as the second one is just a wrapper that gives you access to the device through its API. So yes, you can use them together. I'm sure you'll find examples on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the permission in the manifest file(if you are using Android, or check others for permission).

Look at the link and find the solution:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html

Below code worked for me.

Handler:

```
var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
var name = new ContactName();
name.givenName = "John";
name.familyName = "AB Hotel";
contact.name = name;
contact.save(onSuccess, onError);
function onSuccess(contact) {
    alert("Save Success");
};
function onError(contactError) {
    alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
};
```

Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```